# Get place id from google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am building php/mysql app for a database of events, that will have an option to reference to the google place entity.

In the user interface I want to make a google map in a modal/popup that that will return the google place id when you select a place.

Is there somethign like that alraedy available from google or do I have to code it from scratch?

**EDIT**: 
I've just found [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), which is half-way what I need. I'll try to add a label and an onClick to get the place id

Comment: It's not allowed: [**you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=de#section_10_1_3)

Comment: i don't think that this falls under that category, because the db will hold information of events taking place at a certain bar/hotel which will reference to google place. Anyway thanks for the notice, will check with a legal advice